# Limiting access on windows 7 machine - strictly to one website

Tags: windows-7, permissions

I have a windows 7 laptop that I want to use at my booth at an upcoming convention.

The only permissions I want to give people on this machine, are rights to navigate our e-catalog which my website hosts.

How could I best achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You could use Microsoft Family Safety (part of the Live Essentials suite) it has this feature. You can BLOCK ALL except for the list of sites that you maintain.

To enable this feature:

select the user in question
go to Web Filtering
turn on web filtering
move the slider all the way up to "Allow List Only"
Separately you can maintain the list of sites that you allow in "Web Filtering Lists".

You could also change the host file to block all but the one site you are allowing. for instace you want only google.com

```
http://www.google.com -> google.com
and then *.*.*.* -> localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to Blacklist or Whitelist the site is to deploy a firewall setup or a proxy setup.

Deploying limiting access rules using GPO or other stuff in the machine would only work with Internet Explorer, but not for other browsers. Also, allowing and blocking using GPO or other stuffs from the windows machine can be easily bypassed.

But if you would like to use GPO, then please take a review at the below article.

http://www.grouppolicy.biz/2010/07/how-to-use-group-policy-to-allow-or-block-urls/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need Steady State.
Download this document: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24373

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link, as the answer can become invalid if the linked page changes or the target site is unreachable/permanently offline.